# sql date time format in search gives different results

Tags: sql, where-clause, milliseconds

I ran a query in which I wanted to find all of the orders that were made starting June 1. Originally I used this code:

```
select blah blah
Where ORDERS.ORDER_DATE > '2016-05-31 23:59:59.999'
```

But the query failed to select orders made on June 1. When I changed the code:

```
Where ORDERS.ORDER_DATE > '2016-05-31 23:59:59.99'
```

I got the June 1 orders. The difference is the  `_2_ nines (.99)` on the end versus `_3_ nines (.999`) in the fractions of seconds. The data always shows 3 figures in the fractions. (Our data only has shows zeros in the fractions of seconds `"XX:XX:XX.000"`)

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I've witnessed that precision issue as well when trying to construct date ranges, so I opted to simplify it.   I'm sure you have already considered this

```
Select ... ORDERS.ORDER_DATE >= '2016-06-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

For sql-server anything over .997 milliseconds rounds up so '`2016-05-31 23:59:59.999`' is evaluated the same as '`2016-06-01 00:00:00.000`'. Couple that with your data is likely more of a `DATE` and you would not get `2016-06-01` as a result.

Because

```
select blah blah
Where ORDERS.ORDER_DATE > '2016-05-31 23:59:59.999'
```

Would be evaluated as

```
select blah blah
Where ORDERS.ORDER_DATE > '2016-06-01 00:00:00.000'
```

So if your DATE is not greater than 6/1 you would not get the result

Why the .99 works bacuase

```
select blah blah
Where ORDERS.ORDER_DATE > '2016-05-31 23:59:59.99'
```

Is Evaluated as

```
select blah blah
Where ORDERS.ORDER_DATE > '2016-05-31 23:59:59.990'
```

Comment: Odds are a million to one, but only > would omit any transactions at midnight.   That said, thanks for the 3 millisecond item.  That is exactly what I witnessed before I changed my approach.

Comment: yes at midnight but think about when you are using a DATETIME filter like this but really applying that to a column that is really just a DATE, which means everything is midnight, then you actually exclude every result on 6/1 not just midnight.  This is a primary reason not to use BETWEEN and to use a >= (or <=) on one side and only the > or < on the other side.....

Comment: The 3ms rounding isn't precisely correct: "datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, as shown in the following table." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx In fact 4 in 10 get rounded to .XX7. This doesnt apply to `datetime2`.

Comment: good point I just think of the 3 milliseconds near midnight because that is really the only one I worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume precision.  When your date string is converted to datetime, it ends up being '2016-06-01'.  I'm guessing your orders have no time component so they have '2016-06-01' also, and since you're doing `>` you are missing them.  The [datetime docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) show the time range is `00:00:00 through 23:59:59.997`.  Try this to see:

```
CREATE TABLE test_date ( dt datetime );
insert into test_date values ('2016-05-31 23:59:59.999')
select * from test_date
-- result: 'June, 01 2016 00:00:00'
```

The right way to do it would be to use the exact start time you want and just use `>=`, and use `<` for the end date along with the exact start time for the next period.

```
select blah blah
Where ORDERS.ORDER_DATE >= '2016-06-01'
```

This will work no matter what date type you use for storing the ORDER_DATE and if you move your database to another system that might have a different precision for the time portion of a datetime object.